# How to get from Seattle to Vancouver, BC during night?

Tags: transportation, vancouver, seattle

I'll be landing in Seattle at midnight from Sunday to Monday and need to be in Vancouver at about 9:00AM.

What are my best options to get to the Vancouver by ground during the night?

Edit:

I'm not going back to Seattle, so I would have to leave rented car in Vancouver.

Also, I can enter Canada only by ground because of my visa status.

Comment: I'm curious - what sort of visa status allows you to enter a country overland, but not by air or sea?

Answer (score 2):

Renting a car, if you are also returning to Seattle later. You can pre-clear driving across the border with the rental car company. [Rome2rio.com](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Seattle/Vancouver) shows public transportation options not one of which is late enough in the day. There is a flight on Delta Airlines that leaves SEA at 7:40 and arrives 8:38, which would get you into downtown Vancouver just a few minutes late.

(I assume you mean Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada. There is also a Vancouver, Washington, which is just north of Portland, Oregon. You probably need a rental car for that, too, but there would be no need to get approval for leaving the USA.)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I mean Vancouver, BC. I edited question and added few more information.

Comment: It appears that a 24-hour one-way car rental SEA airport to Vancouver will run you about US $150 (Kayak search, better may be available with effort).

Comment: Unfortunately can't find $150 rate. I'll landing in Seattle at midnight from 1st to 2nd May.

Comment: All I can say is good luck with finding a better rate. You might consider bidding at Priceline (you make a bid and don't find out which company unless bid is accepted. No refunds.)